# Returning the next alphabetic item in a list after that word, improve performance

Tags: python, performance, list, sorting, dictionary

Hi I want to have an efficient code for returning the next alphabetic item after that word. For example in the list below return the lion when dog is entered. I need to specify input over and over again and therefore could benefit from a presorted list and save the O(nlogn) time everytime.

The  code is running as intended, I just want it to make faster for a very long list.

```
a = ['donkey','alligator','zebra','monkey','dog','cat','lion','bull','ant']

## Output of dog should be: lion

input_word ='dog'

def get_next(input_word):
    b = sorted(a[a.index(input_word):])
    d = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(b)} 
    try: 
        return(b[d[input_word]+1])
    except:
        if len(d)==1:
            return("Last value")
        else:
            return("No value greater than input")

print(get_next(input_word))
```

Edit: The next element should be alphabetically next to dog, so the first element that has alphabet starting after the alphabet 'd' and after the 'dog' in the list is lion.

Edit2: More examples, if the list is a = ['x', 'z', 'y']
If input is x the result should be y, if input is y the output should be 'Last word' and if the input is z then the output should be 'No value greater than input'

Comment: Why should an input of "dog" give "lion" as output? Isn't the next item "cat"?

Comment: The next element should be alphabetically next to dog, so the first element after the alphabet 'd' and after the 'dog' in the list is lion

Comment: But alphabetically the next word after "dog" is "donkey"...

Comment: Ok, so if the list is `a = ['x', 'z', 'y']` and the input is `input_word = 'x'`, should the result be "z" or "y"?

Comment: if input is x the result should be y, if input is y the output should be 'Last word' and if the input is z then the output should be No value greater than input

Comment: Ok. You should [edit] all that critical information into the question though. As it is, the question is unclear and hard to understand.

Comment: done, added the examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient solution is to pre-compute a dict that maps each word to the next word. Instead of searching through the list every time, you'll be able to get the correct result instantly just by looking it up in the dict:

```
a = ['donkey','alligator','zebra','monkey','dog','cat','lion','bull','ant']

next_word_dict = {}
for i, word in enumerate(a):
    # from the remaining words, filter out those are
    # alphabetically smaller than the current word
    itr = (w for w in a[i+1:] if w > word)

    # from those words, find the one that's first
    # in the alphabet
    try:
        next_word = min(itr)
    except ValueError:
        # if we couldn't find a greater word, set
        # an appropriate error message
        if i == len(a)-1:
            next_word = 'Last value'
        else:
            next_word = 'No value greater than input'

    next_word_dict[word] = next_word
```

The `get_next` function is now trivially defined as

```
def get_next(input_word):
    return next_word_dict[input_word]
```

And to verify that it works correctly:

```
>>> get_next('dog')
'lion'
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting, maybe try different logic  when you have to process unsorted array everytime:

```
def get_next_optimized(input_word):
    # Collect only animals who are alphabetically greater than input word
    b = [animal for animal in a if animal[0] > input_word[0]]

    return min(b) if len(b) > 0 else ("No value greater than input")
```

Or else, if you have access to presorted list, try a generator expression -

```
def get_next_optimized_pre_sorted(input_word):
    next_alphabet_word_generator = (animal for animal in sorted_a if animal[0] > input_word[0])

    return next(next_alphabet_word_generator)
```

Keep in mind to do sanity check and validation for input. Specifically for cases where input_word is empty or you could have an empty element in a. Change code to suit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, this is good stuff but still can take O(n) time even with the pre-sorted list. The solution provided by Aran-Fey takes O(1) time after the the pre-computed dictionary is made once. So I can make large number of queries to that.